# Absolute positioned child element is being cut in y-axis if parent has `overflow-x: hidden`

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, overflow, css-position

I'm trying to have an absolute positioned child to overflow its container, only in the y-axis.

The catch is that once the container has `overflow-x: hidden`, the child does not overflow in the y-axis. Not sure why...

It should look like this:
[example for expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oQ0C.png)

Yet, the received behavior is that the child is being cut (run snippet to see).

```css
#d1 {
  background: #efe;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 125px;
}

#d2 {
  position: relative;
  background: #fee;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

#d3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  background: #eef;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/><br/>
<div id="d1" >
  <div id="d2" >
    <div id="d3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if either `overflow` properties is `hidden`, `scroll` or `auto` and the other property is `visible`, it will implicitly compute to `auto`. use the devtools and check the computed section. You may either restructure the html, or use [**`clip`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x)

Comment: Thanks on explaining the devtools trick. I now understand the issue. Can you elaborate on how `clip` can be used?

Comment: clip instead of hidden `overflow-x: clip;` i linked the MDN page, the support doesn't seem to be wide as it still experimental

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the d3 out of d2, then add position relative to d1 :

```css
#d1 {
  position: relative;
  background: #efe;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 125px;
}

#d2 {
  position: relative;
  background: #fee;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

#d3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  background: #eef;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/><br/>
<div id="d1" >
  <div id="d2" ></div>
  <div id="d3"></div>
</div>
```